# Javascript - When the image is rotated, it doesn't keep its ratio/size

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, image-resizing

I have just started to learn javascript, HTML5 and CSS. I'm developing a PWA (progressive web app) that can take a picture, crop, rotate, and download.

So the rotation is working. However when my image is rotated, it doesn't keep his ratio/size.

Here an example from my pc when the image is not **rotated yet and in reverse** (working fine) (Its original size is 1920x1080):
[image]

[image]

And when it's rotated vertically, it doesn't keep his ratio/size. The height is too much (my current problem):
[image]

It's like the image is retaking its original size... I have to scrolldown to see the rest of the picture. It can be annoying if the image is too long in height.

Does anyone have any idea how to keep the same ratio/size when the image is rotated vertically?

I'm using a library to rotate my image, [JavaScript-Load-Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image)

```js
var format = "image/jpeg"
var jpegQuality = 0.4

/**
 * Rotate by left the picture when the button is tapped
 */
function rotateLeftButtonTapped() {
  document.getElementById('btn-rotate-left-photo').onclick = function() {
    loadImage(document.getElementById('pictureFromCamera').src, function(img) {
        var imgUrl = img.toDataURL(format, jpegQuality)
        document.getElementById('pictureFromCamera').setAttribute("src", imgUrl)
      }, {
        orientation: 8
      } // Options
    )
  }
}

/**
 * Rotate by right the picture when the button is tapped
 */
function rotateRightButtonTapped() {
  document.getElementById('btn-rotate-right-photo').onclick = function() {
    loadImage(document.getElementById('pictureFromCamera').src, function(img) {
        var imgUrl = img.toDataURL(format, jpegQuality)
        document.getElementById('pictureFromCamera').setAttribute("src", imgUrl)
      }, {
        orientation: 6
      } // Options
    )
  }
}
```

```css
#pictureFromCamera {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.figure-wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Set the download button at the right bottom of the preview */

#btn-download-photo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}


/* Set the remove button at the right top of the preview */

#btn-remove-photo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<button class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-padding-large w3-section" id="btn-rotate-left-photo">
      <i class="fa fa-rotate-left"></i>
    </button>

<button class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-padding-large w3-section" id="btn-rotate-right-photo">
      <i class="fa fa-rotate-right"></i>
    </button>

<div class="figure-wrapper">
  <img id="pictureFromCamera" />
  <button id="btn-download-photo">
          <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download
        </button>
  <button id="btn-remove-photo">
          <i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Delete
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it to make a [mcve]

Comment: You need to use the `minWidth`, etc options to control the size. As far as I can tell, the image simply fills the available width, so it's initially zoomed out to an arbitrary width. In order to retain that width, you have to use it as minHeight and maxHeight when the image is rotated by 90°. Also note that when `rotateLeftButtonTapped` is called, it assigns a click handler to the rotate button, so if this function is only called once, the code will work, but in that case the function's name doesn't make sense.

Comment: Adding a `max-height` to your image container should fix it.

Comment: Your `#pictureFromCamera` is set to have always 100% width. This doesn't work as you want it to work, it depends on image dimensions. Try to work with min/max css options. Or you can try to use options object for load image lib and set some dimensions.

Comment: Try to use `contain: true` in [options object](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image#contain).

Comment: Thanks you everyone !